# Ryacas leaves 'restart' unevaluated

Tags: r, yacas

The Yacas tutorial claims:

> A session can be restarted (forgetting all previous definitions and results) by typing `restart`. All memory is erased in that case.

But for me, that doesn't happen in Ryacas (version 1.3.1.1):

```
> yac_cli()
Enter Yacas commands here. Type quit to return to R
Yacas->xy
[1] xy
Yacas->xy := 37*73
[1] 2701
Yacas-> xy
[1] 2701
Yacas->restart
[1] restart
Yacas->xy
[1] 2701
```

Initially, `xy` is not bound to a value.  After the assignment, it's bound to 2701.  Problem: the expression `restart` is returned un-evaluated, and has no effect.  I expected `xy` to be unbound again.

My motivation behind this:  I created some global rules with `<--` and want to get rid of them.  It sounds like `restart` should do the trick.